# browser gets disconnected after initializing

Tags: puppeteer

Here is the snippet of code in my `node 8.12.0` app:

```
var browser, page;

//launch browser 
(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    page = await browser.newPage();   
})();

//start cron job  
cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  (async () => {
    await page.goto('https://www.mysitedotcom/admin/');  <== cause error

    //doing something with web page and db
    ........
  )}();
}); // cron.schedule

(async() => {
  browser.close();
})();
```

The `cron` job fires every minute. The webpage above was not opened (`goto` did not work) and here is the error:

```
(node:3232) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!
    at Connection.NavigatorWatcher._eventListeners.helper.addEventListener (C:\d\code\js\wbot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:1146:117)
```

The launch of `browser & page` is purposely left out of the `cron.schedule` so one time creation of `browser` will work for `cron.schedule` as long as the session is alive. But the problem is that the `browser` somehow was `disconnected` when it gets to the `cron.schedule`. I don't see the reason why.  What I am missing here?

Comment: Can you add a bit more code? Are you running corn every second/minute? Why is it a async function inside another function?

Comment: `Ma Abu Taher`, added more explanation of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Due to asynchronous nature** these lines closes the browser almost instantly. Remove them or move them somewhere else if you need to keep the browser open.

```
(async() => {
  browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: I removed this completely. It seems that the `browser` gets disconnected out of the `async` function. just moved the `cron.schedule` inside of the `async` of `launching browser and see how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `await browser.close();` at the end?

This will wait for the browser to close completely.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it